# Insert Ignore efficiency over a period of time

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

Here's the situation

Over the time  I will have a MySQL database with around 40-50 thousand records. The records are pulled from a text file (through a PHP script, after a button on the web page is pressed) that updates itself (appends) 2-3 times a day from another department (not in my hand). I have to insert these new records in the database (when the button on my web page is pressed) and ignore the one's that are already there. For that purpose I am using `"Insert Ignore"` statement.

My question is over the time when the records grow up (40-50 thousand) will the `"Insert Ignore"` statement take long time to execute (my browser timeout is 5 seconds and I can't go beyond that). There would never be more than 300 unique records to update at one single time and my table just has 2 columns (if that matters). The system is working perfectly now but I want to be prepared for the future. I have no way to test his so I'll appreciate if someone can tell me based on his/her experience.

Comment: How big do you expect to grow?

Comment: As I mentioned I have to be prepared for 40-50 thousand records. Around 80 thousand (upper limit)

Comment: Well, by modern standards it's nothing. You should, however, get a test machine (on Amazon EC2, for example), recreate your environment there and test with 100k records.

Comment: sure.. I'll try that.. but will the environment be totally replicated. For example I do not have a solid state drive and I am running it on MAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a heavy name/value system with `INSERT IGNORE` and also `INSERT ... On DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
When table became large, I am "splitting" today info (updated heavy) and archive.

Also, I doesn't know what is your system design, but in my system (simple name/counter) I am saving one-week detailed information and the archive is grouped to get small and less rows.

Good luck!

Comment: Splitting and Archiving is a good idea. But among the two columns one is a primary key. If you split, archive don't you have a chance to get duplicates.

Comment: I do not know what is your system design. If you can't, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

A table with 50k records shouldn't give you performance issues with something like that.  Now if you had 50 million, I might change my tune.

As Moshe L indicated, there are a couple of ways to go about this.  Here's a link to an article that measures the [performance of ON DUPLICATE KEY vs. INSERT IGNORE](http://www.eddieoneverything.com/programming/mysql-performance-tip-on-duplicate-key-is-faster-than-insert-ignore-but-failing-with-a-duplicate-key-error-is-a-lot-faster.php) on a database of 9 million records.  According to that, you're going down the right path.